# How pass in JavaScript variable html with double and single quotes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass html code to a variable that contains double and single quotes, I tried to do this inside html script tag, everything works except IE11

```
<script>
const partials = {
   header: `
     <div class="class-name">
      <div class="child" data-with-single-quotes=''></div>
    </div>
  `
}
</script>
```

How can I put such html into a variable in IE11 and still not using escaping like `\"` and without joining through `+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using single quote instead of backquote.

```
      <script>
           const partials = {
                      header:  '<div class="class-name">\
                    <div class="child" data-with-single-quotes=\'\'></div></div>'
                   }
      </script>
```